# C# Exchange -> Outlook Item Attachment

Tags: c#, email, outlook, exchange-server

Im trying to get (from my Exchange Server Outlook) my Outlook contact´s.
im Using using C# and email.Attachments.AddItemAttachment(variable);
I have already a connection to Outlook and can send with my script. I load all Outlookfolders.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;
//using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MAPIFolder;
//Imports outlook = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook

namespace HelloWorld
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010_SP1);
     RedirectionUrlValidationCallback);
            service.Url = new Uri("*******");

          service.Credentials = new WebCredentials("******","******");  service.TraceEnabled = true;
          service.TraceFlags = TraceFlags.All;
          EmailMessage email = new EmailMessage(service);


          /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            var outlookApplication = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
            NameSpace mapiNamespace = outlookApplication.GetNamespace("MAPI");
            MAPIFolder contacts = mapiNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(OlDefaultFolders.olFolderContacts);
            for (int i = 1; i < contacts.Items.Count + 1; i++)
            {
                var contact = (ContactItem)contacts.Items[i];
                itemAttachment.Name="contact.FullName";
                Console.WriteLine(contact.Email1Address);
                Console.WriteLine();


            }
              var testcontact = "adasd";
            /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

            email.ToRecipients.Add("********");
            email.Sender = new   Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.EmailAddress("*****");

            email.Subject = "Test subj";
            email.Body = new MessageBody("Test txt");
            email.Attachments.AddItemAttachment(testcontact);

            email.SendAndSaveCopy();

        }
        private static bool RedirectionUrlValidationCallback(string redirectionUrl)
        {
            // The default for the validation callback is to reject the URL.
            bool result = false;

            Uri redirectionUri = new Uri(redirectionUrl);

            // Validate the contents of the redirection URL. In this simple validation
            // callback, the redirection URL is considered valid if it is using HTTPS
            // to encrypt the authentication credentials. 
            if (redirectionUri.Scheme == "https")
            {
                result = true;
            }
            return result;
        }

    }
}
```

Does anybody know what the right Syntax is for

> email.Attachments.AddItemAttachment(testcontact);

?

Answer (score 0):

The [Add](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff869553.aspx) function of the [Attachments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff864730.aspx) class creates a new attachment in the Attachments collection. You just need to pass the [olEmbeddeditem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff868693.aspx) value as a second parameter:

```
    attachments = mailContainer.Attachments;
    attachment = attachments.Add(mailToAttach, 
       Outlook.OlAttachmentType.olEmbeddeditem, 1, "The attached e-mail");
```

See [How To: Add an existing Outlook e-mail message as an attachment](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/08/12/how-to-add-existing-e-mail-message-as-attachment/) for more information.

Also I have noticed the following line of code:

```
 contacts.Items.Count
```

Don't use multiple dots in the single line of code. I always recommend breaking the chain of calls and declaring each property or method call on separate line of code. It allows to releasa underlying COM objects instantly and avoid possible issues. See [Systematically Releasing Objects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb623945%28v=office.12%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)  for more information.

Comment: i dont know where i have to add youre code. Could you post something from my code that i knew where i have to add this?